# Bluetooth version supported by iPhone 8

Tags: iphone, bluetooth

How do I check version of Bluetooth on iPhone 8 and then update to bluetooth 5.0
Purpose is to sync more than one device when pairing

Answer (score 2):

According to everymac.com, both [iPhone 8](https://everymac.com/systems/apple/iphone/specs/apple-iphone-8-att-t-mobile-global-a1905-specs.html) and [iPhone 8 Plus](https://everymac.com/systems/apple/iphone/specs/apple-iphone-8-plus-att-t-mobile-global-a1897-specs.html) come with Bluetooth 5.0.

PS: Actually, the Bluetooth standard supported is defined by the hardware and can't be changed.